# The softmax function, why?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science-model

We know that Softmax usually applied to multi-class labels with the function of $e^{a}\over \sum e^{a}$.

My question is will a function like $a^{2} \over \sum a^{2}$ mostly work also? If not, why?

Here a stand output from last activation.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to the alternative you suggested, the advantage of the softmax is that exponentiating works well with log loss, as described in [section 6.2.2. of the Deep Learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html):

The aim is to define an activation function which outputs values

> [...] between 0 and 1, and [...] the logarithm of the number to be well behaved for gradient-based optimization of the log-likelihood

and,

> As with the logistic sigmoid, the use of the exp function works well when training the softmax to output a target value y using maximum log-likelihood. In this case, we wish to maximize $\log P(y=i;z) =\log softmax(z)_i$. Deﬁning the softmax in terms of exp is natural because thelogin the log-likelihood can undo the exp of the softmax [...]

A disadvantage being that

> Many objective functions other than the log-likelihood do not work as well with the softmax function. Speciﬁcally, objective functions that do not use a log to undo the exp of the softmax fail to learn when the argument to the exp becomes very negative, causing the gradient to vanish. In particular, squared error is a poor loss function for softmax units and can fail to train the model to change its output, even when the model makes highly conﬁdent incorrect predictions [...]

For more details I recommend reading the linked section of the book.